# Is it safe to run Ceph with 2-way replication on 3 OSD nodes?

Tags: ceph

Let say I want to achieve maximum useable capacity with data resilience on this 3 OSD nodes setup where each node contains 2x 1TB OSDs.

Is it safe run 3 Ceph nodes with 2-way replication?

What are the pros and cons of using 2-way? Will it cause data split-brain?

Last but not least, what domain fault tolerance will it be running on 2-way replication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, even three replica is not enough, e.g. if ssd disks (from cache) fail together or one by one.

http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2015-October/005672.html

For two osd you can even set manually 1 replica for minimum and 2 replicas for maximum (I didn't managed to set it automatically in the case of one failed osd of all three osds):

`osd pool default size = 2` # Write an object 2 times

`osd pool default min size = 1` # Allow writing 1 copy in a degraded state

But this command: `ceph osd pool set mypoolname set min_size 1` 
sets it for a pool, not just the default settings.

For `n = 4` nodes each with 1 osd and 1 mon and settings of replica `min_size 1` and `size 4` three osd can fail, only one mon can fail (the monitor quorum means more than half will survive). `4 + 1` number of monitors is required for two failed monitors (at least one should be external without osd). For `8` monitors (four external monitors) three mon can fail, so even three nodes each with `1` osd and `1` mon can fail. I am not sure that setting of `8` monitors is possible.

Thus, for three nodes each with one monitor and osd the only reasonable settings are replica `min_size 2` and `size 3` or 2. Only one node can fail.
If you have an external monitors, if you set `min_size` to `1` (this is very dangerous) and `size` to `2` or `1` the `2` nodes can be down. But with one replica (no copy, only original data) you can loose your job very soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I should stick with default replicas 3 then.

I goal was to go with maximum useable storage capacity with 3 OSD nodes, still having those redundancy should one fails, but would like to avoid data split-brain. :D

Comment: Monitor quorum is the main problem and of course 3 replica (min_size 2 and size 3) with a possibility of one failed node is the best option.